# Inversed array but not a hashmap

Tags: java, arrays, indexing, hashmap

In Java, I have an unsorted `int[] values = new int[100];` array. All the values are unique (different) and they are uncomparable (no way to sort). Can I construct a kind of inversed function which will give me an index of a certain value in the array if I specify that value?

Currently done it using a hashmap:

```
IntIntMap indices = new IntIntOpenHashMap(100, 1);

for (int i = 0; i < 100; i++) {
     indices.put(values[i], i);
}
```

Any other solution? Would prefer a faster one.

Comment: Erm, let us know when you come up with something faster than O(1).

Comment: What is an IntIntOpenHashMap?  If it's a hashmap you've created, and it's running slowly, I suggest reviewing your code.  However, as Brian noted, hashmap access is O(1) (amortized), so you can't really get faster...

Comment: In what way could you possibly not be able to sort integers?

Comment: IntIntOpenHashMap seems pretty efficient, but is size of array is small and number of reads for each created table is low simple linear search could be faster. If you know maximum value for integers in array and it is reasonable size for array you can create array where original index written on position pointed to by original value.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you could create your own hash function or research a specific one for your case. It depends on the structure of the values and whether this is truly a bottleneck in the program.